# Bootstrap 4 custom control no have cursor pointer

Tags: bootstrap-4, custom-controls

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Toggle this switch element</label>
</div>
```

Why custom control no have cursor pointer?
I try style="cursor:pointer" or apply my class cursor-pointer by no work

Comment: Can you provide the css please ?

Comment: the css is Bootstrap v4.3.1 standard

Answer (score 3):

add these lines to your css :

```
.custom-switch .custom-control-label::before { cursor: pointer; }
.custom-switch .custom-control-label::after { cursor: pointer; }
.custom-switch .custom-control-input:disabled ~ .custom-control-label::before { cursor: not-allowed; }
.custom-switch .custom-control-input:disabled ~ .custom-control-label::after { cursor: not-allowed; }
```